# Allocation of temp directory inside tomcat installation base results in error due to read only property

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I am moving a project from Eclipse to Intellij IDEA. I have already added the jars to the Project Structure -> Libraries and added them to the module as a dependency. The tomcat server is up and running so navigation of the web application is working correctly.
Unfortunately, when using the jar to create an excel file I get the error java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Could not create temporary directory 'C:\path_to_tomcat_installation\temp\poifiles\'
My Question is how/why is eclipse/tomcat able to use the poi to create a excel file without this error and Intellij IDEA cannot

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Does it work if Tomcat is started outside of IDE and the app is deployed manually via the war file?

Comment: I attempted to do a manual deploy, but unfortunately my environment is set up based on deploying/running inside the ide. As such I was unable to quickly configure tomcat to run outside of eclipse or intellij.  However, upon further investigation I found out some new information that may be helpful. Apparently eclipse overrides the CATALINA_TMPDIR indirectly by modifying the CATALINA_BASE reference. In doing so the temp directory is placed inside the eclipse workspace and is apparently writable by eclipse/tomat. I also discovered that I could create a windows enviornment variable

Comment: When I set the variable to a writable location I was able to create the excel file without error. I am guessing that this would be considered more  of a hack and not the preferred means to accomplish this task.

Comment: If your default temp directory is not writable, using something like `-Djava.io.tmpdir=c:/new/temp/dir` to override it seems to be a good workaround.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, thank you for your help in my journey to learn Intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there are a lot of questions and answers on stackoverflow about changing the value of java.io.tmpdir.

Initially I set a windows system variable CATALINA_TMPDIR to c:/new/temp/dir, but as this is a system wide setting I ultimately decided to not use that method.

The simplest method and most direct was to use CrazyCoders suggestion.
Under Run -> Edit Configurations.
In the Server tab of the Tomcat Server, in the VM options box enter -Djava.io.tmpdir=c:/new/temp/dir

Comment: @CrazyCoder I could use some help on this issue again, the folder has defaulted back to the read only location that was previously used and I don't know why. Thank you for any insight you might have.